# Recursive hierarchy grouping by string delimiting in SSRS 2016?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, hierarchy, sqlclr

I have a SQL Server database as my data source for which my rows contain a path delimited by \

For example:

"\Foo\Bar"

is a folder containing

"\Foo\Bar\Baz".

My database contains a column storing an absolute path, and I would like to have a recursive hierarchy table based on ownership of folders to child folders.

My data is stored like this:

```
+--------------+
| PATH         |
+--------------+
| \Foo         |
+--------------+
| \Foo\Bar     |
+--------------+
| \Foo\Bar\Baz |
+--------------+
| \Foo\Bar\Qux |
+--------------+
| \Foo2        |
+--------------+
```

and I would like to represent it like this

```
+----------+
| PATH     |
+----------+
| \Foo     |
+----------+
|   \Bar   |
+----------+
|     \Baz |
+----------+
|     \Qux |
+----------+
| \Foo2    |
+----------+
```

I have already written some helpful CLR stored procedures for this process:

One allow me to get the children of a given parent path (e.g. passing in "\Foo\Bar" returns rows "\Foo\Bar\Baz" and "\Foo\Bar\Qux")

Another allows me to extract the bottom-most level name of a path (e.g. extracting "\Baz" from "\Foo\Bar\Baz").

Is it possible to have a table generated in this fashion using the [SSRS Recursive Hierarchy Grouping Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-recursive-hierarchy-group-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) with the way my data is being stored? Or will this task require a modification to my database schema?

Comment: Have you looked into the `HierarchyID` data type?

Comment: I have, but I'd like to avoid changes to my schema if possible. Even if I did implement a HierarchyID column into my schema, is my desired end result possible with Report Builder?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Report Builder :-(

Comment: No problem, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Something's not clear.   In your report, do you want the results in your question to appear in one simple text column?   Or is that your representation of an expandable tree structure, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify that. I would like for the results to be in a single column with collapsible/expandable groupings, each of which would have their own values for the additional data columns that I haven't shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the recursive grouping feature, you will need a parent-child hierarchy that can be used to join a parent with it's children. For example, you can use a query like this, based on your table, that will retrieve also the last folder name and the path to the parent Folder (flen is the length of the folder name):

```
SELECT [PATH]
  , RIGHT([PATH], p.flen) AS FOLDER
  , LEFT([PATH], LEN([PATH]) - p.flen) AS [PARENT]
FROM FolderTable
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([PATH])))) p (flen);
```

The data returned will look like this:

[image: The Dataset]

You can then create a report, add the Data Source and a Dataset based on the query above. You can then add a table to the report, it only needs to have one column. Display the field `FOLDER` of the Dataset in that column.

Done so, change the properties of the *Details* group (under Row Groups):

- Under *General* properties, add the `PATH` field as the **Group expression**
- Under *Advanced* properties, add the `PARENT` field as the **Recursive parent**

If we look at the result, it doesn't look nicely yet:

[image: Result Without Padding]

To display the children a little bit indented, we can use the `Level` function in an expression for the *Padding Left* property of the FOLDER TextBox (taken from an example by Microsoft):

```
=CStr(2 + (Level()*10)) + "pt"
```

Now, I guess we arrived where we wanted to go:

[image: Formatted Result]

Comment: This seems like a better approach than what came up with from a performance standpoint. I will attempt to implement this in a separate report and compare. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. For anyone in my position, here is what you do:

Create a table with your desired values.

Add a Row Group on your path field (or equivalent string with a hierarchical delimiter).

Right click your new row group and pick Group Properties.

Add a new Group Expression, Group on the hierarchical field.

Go to the advanced tab.

Click the expression (fx) button for Recursive Parent.

Here you will use regex to denote what is a parent. For example, my expression is:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Fields!Qualifier.Value, ".*(?=\\\\)").Value
```

Where "Qualifier" is the field name, and my delimiter is the \ character.

To adapt this for your usage, change the field name in bold to your name, and change the regex parent matching pattern to what fits your schema.

=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Fields!**Qualifier**.Value, "**.*(?=\\)**").Value

A demo of my regex is [here](http://regexr.com/3spcf), which essentially grabs the full path *minus* the last element and delimiter.

If anyone has issues with this feel free to ask. It was a huge pain because nothing like this has been documented.